# Count the group occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe

```
      id webpage
       1   google
       2    bing
       3   google
       4   google
       5   yahoo
       6   yahoo
       7   google
       8   google
```

Would like to count the groups

like

```
       id webpage count
       1   google  1
       2    bing   2
       3   google  3
       4   google  3
       5   yahoo   4
       6   yahoo   4
       7   google  5
       8   google  5
```

I have tried using the `cumcount` or `ngroup` when using groupby it is grouping all occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to `cumsum()` over the state transitions. Every time `webpage` differs from the previous row you increase your `count`.

```
df["count"] = (df.webpage != df.webpage.shift()).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I m not so used to pandas but I just made a quick dataframe and made a program to get the expected result. I made a variable count whose value increase when we find a data which is different than last data (_data) the current count value is added to the list of all counts then finally after getting all the counts. the count colum is added to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
webpage_list=['google', 'bing','google','google','yahoo','yahoo','google','google']
df=pd.DataFrame(webpage_list,columns=['webpage'])
count=0
counts=[]
_data=''
for data in df['webpage']:
   if data!=_data:
       count+=1
   _data=data
   counts.append(count)
df['count']=counts
print(df)
```